# Insertar script en google sites

Tags: script

Ante todo perdón por mi ignorancia.

Estoy siguiendo un curso de javascript y quería ver los resultados en una página real.
Para ello he creado en google sites una página cualquiera.

Pruebo un código sencillo y no hay forma de que funcione ni de que se vea nada

En un primer lugar inserto

`<script> alert("Hola Mundo"); </script>`

Después de mirar foros

`<html><body><script type="text/javascript"  alert("Hola Mundo"); </script></body></html>`

Seguro que debe ser una cosa muy simple, pero no puedo avanzar en nada.

Gracias y perdón por el atrevimiento.

Comment: No veo que Google sites ejecute los alert. Sin embargo, sí permite usar `console.log('Hola mundo');` en un fragmento embebido. Por ejemplo, en el embed le puse `<script type="text/javascript">alert('something!'); console.log("Hola Mundo"); </script>` y sólo veo la parte en la consola del navegador. Suena a un entorno bieeeen controlado. Por qué no montas algo local para comenzar? :)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. En local sí me funciona, pero deseaba poder verlo en una página real. Vi que Google Sites permitía el uso de scripts pero ya veo que no funciona salvo que los vincules fuera del sitio.

Comment: Un XAMPP en tu máquina es muy real! Tener cosas en un sitio público sólo es diferente porque está expuesto a ataques todo el tiempo y es un fastidio ajustar todo para que los dominios y las reglas queden bien. :)

Comment: Ok, gracias. Así lo haré.